# pagination use seek method (keyset)

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, pagination

I have problem about how to do pagination use seek method,
in my query I need to
1.sort and order multiple column
2.some column not unique

For example if data is like below and do query `select * from ... order by name asc, status asc ....(other column), id asc` and get `8 1 3 10 2 5 6 7 9 4`
Now if I want to do pagination select 2 rows each time,
first page same as above query just add limit 2 `select * from ... order by name asc, status asc ....(other column), id asc`.
How to select next page ?

If just id column I know it is check order , if asc then find id bigger then biggest id in previous result.
But how to solve if column is mutiple and some is not unique value?

```
id | name | status | ...
1 b 0
2 b 0
3 b 0
4 j 0
5 f 0
6 g 0
7 h 0
8 a 0
9 i 0
10 b 0
```

Q 1.

```
// example table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "table"(
    "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
    "create_date" timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    "create_by_user_id" integer NOT NULL,
    "last_modified_date" timestamp without time zone DEFAULT NULL,
    "last_modified_by_user_id" integer DEFAULT NULL,
    "url_id" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    "status" integer NOT NULL,
    "rank" integer NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar DEFAULT NULL,
    "name_slug" varchar DEFAULT NULL,
    "description" varchar DEFAULT NULL,
    "start_date" date NOT NULL,
    "end_date" date NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id"),
    UNIQUE ("url_id"),
    FOREIGN KEY ("create_by_user_id") REFERENCES "user" ("id") ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
  );

// select first page
SELECT * FROM table 
  ORDER BY name ASC NULLS LAST
   , status ASC NULLS LAST
   , rank DESC NULLS LAST
   , id ASC
  LIMIT 2;

// select next page  How do I know use <, >, <=, >= in below ?
SELECT * FROM table
  WHERE name ?? operator prev_end_name
    AND  status ??  prev_end_status
    AND  rank ??  prev_end_rank
    AND  id ?? prev_end_id
  ORDER BY name ASC NULLS LAST
   , status ASC NULLS LAST
   , rank DESC NULLS LAST
   , id ASC
  LIMIT 2;
```

I do some research all related post I found online is showing same thing use previous id ... but in real life usage how to make it order by different and multiple column?  like instagram api also use previous id but how to sort and order by many other column..
http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page
http://leopard.in.ua/2014/10/11/postgresql-paginattion
https://blog.jooq.org/2013/10/26/faster-sql-paging-with-jooq-using-the-seek-method/
https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/03/30/five-ways-to-paginate/
https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/2crwyg/we_need_tool_support_for_keyset_pagination/

Please don't provide the way use page number set offset limit to pagination, its not what I looking for.

Q 2.
I'm doing this with node.js,
not use any query builder orm library,
part of my model build the query like below,
so it's so hard to add seek method if need to do order with many column.
Wondering people usually how to do this in real life big site nodejs + postgres application, 
any suggestion will be appreciate!

```
if (typeof request.data.query.pagination_type != 'undefined') {
  if (request.data.query.pagination_type == 'seek') {
    if (typeof request.data.query.sort_order_list != 'undefined') {
      for (var i = 0; i < request.data.query.sort_order_list.length; i++) {
        if (request.data.query.sort_order_list[i].sort == 'name') {
          if (typeof request.data.query.prev_end_name != 'undefined') {
            if (!start) { dbQuery += ' AND'; } else { dbQuery += ' WHERE'; }
            if (start) { start = false; }
            if (request.data.query.sort_order_list[i].order == 'asc') {
              dbQuery += ` ee.name < $` + paramsIndex;
            } else if (request.data.query.sort_order_list[i].order == 'desc') {
              dbQuery += ` ee.name > $` + paramsIndex;
            }
            paramsIndex++;
            dbParams.push(request.data.query.prev_end_name);
          }
        } else if (request.data.query.sort_order_list[i].sort == 'start_date') {
...
```

query output something like

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM task t WHERE 
  t.status = $1 
  AND t.rank >= $2 
  AND t.end_date >= $3 
  AND t.rank < $4 
  AND t.end_date < $5 
  AND t.name < $6 
  AND t.start_date > $7 
  ORDER BY t.rank asc NULLS LAST, 
    t.end_date asc NULLS LAST, 
    t.name asc NULLS LAST, 
    t.start_date desc NULLS LAST LIMIT $8
```

Comment: And what's wrong with the regular `OFFSET` + `LIMIT` approach? This is how it is normally done.

Comment: Nothing wrong,  I use offset + limit now, and provide two params input, page or previous id(if input previous id use row_number find offset).  I just want to try and learn the seek method (keyset)

Answer (score 1):

Seek method requires an unique column to sort from. If you want to sort by status asc, what you have to do is something like this:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM task t WHERE 
  t.status = $1 
  AND t.rank >= $2 
  AND t.end_date >= $3 
  AND t.rank < $4 
  AND t.end_date < $5 
  AND t.name < $6 
  AND t.start_date > $7 
  ORDER BY t.status asc NULLS LAST, 
    t.id asc NULLS LAST
LIMIT $8
```

This will give you a page sorted by status, and, if the status is the same, sorted by ID. You can do this with N columns, always remember to put ID last.

In order to retrieve the next page, you will need the last item's status/ID, and the query will be something like:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM task t WHERE 
  t.status = $1 
  AND t.rank >= $2 
  AND t.end_date >= $3 
  AND t.rank < $4 
  AND t.end_date < $5 
  AND t.name < $6 
  AND t.start_date > $7

--Pagination Where Clause
  AND t.status > $9
  OR (t.status = $9 AND t.id > $10)
 
  ORDER BY t.status asc NULLS LAST, 
    t.id asc NULLS LAST
LIMIT $8
```

Where $9 is the last item's status and $10 is the last item's id (from the previous page).
The `>` changes to `<` on the pagination where clause if you want to sort by DESC.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming your Ids are a numeric complete set (no deleted rows) you can order a subquery by Id, have the WHERE clause limit to page number (0 for first page returns 0 through 10, 1 returns 11 through 20, etc).

```
    SELECT TOP 10 * FROM
        ( SELECT  *
        FROM Table
        WHERE Id > 5 * @PageNumber
        ORDER BY Id )
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but does that become the other way like offset, limit  (http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page ) , and also the id not complete set there is deleted rows ...